# Браузеры автоматически увеличивают масштаб страницы. Как бороться?

Tags: javascript, css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

После появления retina дисплеев и других экранов с высоким разрешением и небольшой диагональю, через некоторое время, браузеры стали по умолчанию увеличивать масштаб страницы для экранов с высоким разрешением.
Теперь, если смотреть одну и туже страницу с одинаковым разрешением экрана, но с разными диагоналями - картинка сильно отличается в масштабах.

**Например:**

экран 15,6 дюйма с физическим разрешением *1920х1080* в Google Chrome отображается как: *1536х759*.

Я, так понимаю, что это связано с:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0>
```

Как сделать по умолчанию, чтобы размер был равен физическому для всех типов устройств, кроме мобильных?
Или, если же я чего не понимаю - прошу просветить.

Comment: А зачем? В результате же на одних дисплеях всё будет слишком мелко, на других слишком крупно

Comment: Действительно, зачем с этим бороться? Я на эту возможность молюсь. Я очень рад ей! Попробуйте убрать `<meta name="viewport" ...`

Comment: Потому что для ретины и подобных писал кастомную верстку, а теперь "картинка" уже не так впечатляюще выглядит.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы масштаб не увеличивался можно задать css свойство для всех объектов `max-width: 1920`;